# Laravel Queues executing very frequent

Tags: laravel, queue, scheduler

Everywhere I read about queues in Laravel I see they should run once per minute.

The issue I have is this one runs 2 or 3 times every second, and I don't know why.

```
php artisan queue:listen
[2022-03-11 16:46:09][2061940] Processing: App\Console\Jobs\Cron\Schedule
[2022-03-11 16:46:09][2061940] Processed:  App\Console\Jobs\Cron\Schedule
[2022-03-11 16:46:09][2061951] Processing: App\Console\Jobs\Cron\Schedule
[2022-03-11 16:46:09][2061951] Processed:  App\Console\Jobs\Cron\Schedule
[2022-03-11 16:46:10][2061968] Processing: App\Console\Jobs\Cron\Schedule
[2022-03-11 16:46:10][2061968] Processed:  App\Console\Jobs\Cron\Schedule
[2022-03-11 16:46:10][2061969] Processing: App\Console\Jobs\Cron\Schedule
[2022-03-11 16:46:10][2061969] Processed:  App\Console\Jobs\Cron\Schedule
[2022-03-11 16:46:10][2061970] Processing: App\Console\Jobs\Cron\Schedule
[2022-03-11 16:46:10][2061970] Processed:  App\Console\Jobs\Cron\Schedule
[2022-03-11 16:46:11][2061972] Processing: App\Console\Jobs\Cron\Schedule
[2022-03-11 16:46:11][2061972] Processed:  App\Console\Jobs\Cron\Schedule
[2022-03-11 16:46:11][2061987] Processing: App\Console\Jobs\Cron\Schedule
[2022-03-11 16:46:11][2061987] Processed:  App\Console\Jobs\Cron\Schedule
```

I have tried:

1. Restarting the server.
2. Clearing caches:

`artisan cache:clear`

`artisan cache:clear redis`

3. Checked for excess rogue queue workers running on server with ps.
4. Checked crontab, all have no crons defined for any user.

I am not really familiar with Laravel, so maybe this is expected behavior,  but I really don't think so, and would like to see that run just once per minute like it is supposed to.

**Edit Added info:**

The queue is called using the backend.Queue service:

`artisan queue:work --tries=5 --sleep=3`

systemctl status backendQueue

```
● backendQueue.service - MMC App API Queue    Loaded: loaded (/home/config/current/services/backendQueue.service; linked; vendor preset: disabled)    Active: active (running) since Fri 2022-03-11 21:42:35 UTC; 17min ago  Main PID: 3077 (php)    CGroup: /system.slice/backendQueue.service            └─3077 /usr/bin/php /home/www/api.app.mymotioncalendar.com/current/artisan queue:work --tries=5 --sleep=3
```

There is a Load Balancer setup and two copies of the same Laravel server running simultaneously, both have queue:work started the same way.

Also this seems odd, but maybe it's correct: In the app/Console/Jobs/Cron/Schedule.php file:

```
public function handle() {
       Artisan::call('schedule:run');     } 
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The interval is defined by whatever you've configured to call `php artisan schedule:run`. If that's crontab, then the shortest interval that can be is 1min. You say it's not crontab, so then the real question is - what is it?

Comment: *Everywhere I read about queues in Laravel I see they should run once per minute.* this is incorrect. The scheduler runs once per minute because it's on the crontab however the queue worker runs as frequently as the `--sleep=X` parameter allows it and by default it does not sleep it just chains jobs

Comment: A system service.  ``systemctl status backendQueue
● backendQueue.service - MMC App API Queue
   Loaded: loaded (/home/config/current/services/backendQueue.service; linked; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2022-03-11 21:42:35 UTC; 17min ago
 Main PID: 3077 (php)
   CGroup: /system.slice/backendQueue.service
           └─3077 /usr/bin/php /home/www/api.app.mymotioncalendar.com/current/artisan queue:work --tries=5 --sleep=3``

Comment: It seems like you may have some unintended cross over between queues and the scheduler. How are you running your queues?

Comment: There is two servers running the queue on each server with a common backend.

Comment: Also this seems odd, but maybe it's correct: In the app/Console/Jobs/Cron/Schedule file:       ``public function handle()
    {
        Artisan::call('schedule:run');
    }
}
``

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer in Laravel Documentation.

Worker Sleep Duration

When jobs are available on the queue, the worker will keep processing jobs with no delay in between them. However, the sleep option determines how long (in seconds) the worker will "sleep" if there are no new jobs available. While sleeping, the worker will not process any new jobs - the jobs will be processed after the worker wakes up again.

So the job queue must be backed up really bad.